# Permission denied when starting MySQL Server from MySQL Workbench in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mysql-workbench

I am using **Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**, i installed **Mysql Workbench** using the **Ubuntu software center**. Now, i am unable to start the server both when i open a connection or i click on **Start Server** button.

The server is configured to run on **localhost:3306** (the default configuration).

Here is the Mysql Workbench Startup Message Log:

```
2016-02-28 12:10:27 - Checked server status: Server is stopped.
2016-02-28 12:10:35 - Checked server status: Server is stopped.
2016-02-28 12:10:50 - Starting server...
2016-02-28 12:10:50 - Executting '/etc/init.d/mysqld start'
2016-02-28 12:10:53 - Checked server status: Server is stopped.
2016-02-28 12:10:59 - Could not stop server. Permission denied
2016-02-28 12:10:59 - Checked server status: Server is stopped.
```

Comment: Not an Ubuntu guru but regular users cannot start and stop services. Do you get prompted for your root password or `sudo` yourself?

Comment: Yes, i was asked for the password, but i don't know what to put because i didn't give any password during the installation.

Comment: What does the prompt say exactly? (Remember we cannot look your monitor over your shoulder). You don't your system's root password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this with root privileges, so you need the ability to use sudo. You will be prompted for *your* password when you do this. If you are not allowed, then you have to apply for sudo access.

I think also your actual problem is you don't have mysql server installed. Not too sure what workbench is. If you want to make databases and tables and store information on the server, you need to install mysql server. At the command prompt:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

to install server. Then to run

```
$ sudo bash
$ service mysql start
or 
$ mysqld_safe
```

Then to find out if it is running

```
$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-02-28 22:31:48 AEDT; 3min 11s ago
```

The line saying "Active: ..." is what you are looking for

Comment: MySQL workbench is a sw that helps to manage different server installation by a client

Comment: The question is about starting and stopping MySQL Server using a specific GUI tool ([MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/common/images/products/MySQL_Workbench_Admin_Start_Stop_Linux.gif)) and your answer suggests using command line instead :-?

Comment: And installing MySQL server. The command line is the most reliable and consistent way to install, start and stop services on Ubuntu